# Applications of Tietze Extension Theorem

Tags: analysis, general-topology

I'm searching for some nice applications of Tietze extension theorem, in any area of mathematics. Can you name some (and possibly give references) to me?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Not really an application, but a nice sharpening is [Whitney's extension theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitney_extension_theorem) which I found quite surprising when I saw it for the first time. The [original article](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307%2F1989708) is very nice and definitely worth having a look at.

Comment: The Tietze Extension theorem can be used to show that the adjunction of two normal spaces is normal assuming of course that you glue on a closed subset of the spaces.

Answer (score 13):

One application I particularly like, from an undergraduate analysis exam problem:

**Theorem:** A metric space $X$ is compact if and only if every continuous real-valued function on $X$ is bounded.

**Proof:** Assume first $X$ is compact. If $f:X\to \mathbb R$ is continuous and unbounded, then we have some sequence $(x_n)$ in $X$ such that $f(x_n)>n,\forall n\in\mathbb N$. Since $X$ is compact, we have some convergent subsequence $(x_{n_k})$, so $\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}f(x_{n_k})=f(\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}x_{n_k})$. But this is impossible, as $f(x_{n_k})\to\infty$, hence any continuous real-valued function is bounded. If instead $X$ is not compact, then we have some sequence $(x_n)$ in $X$ which has no convergent subsequence. Hence every convergent sequence with terms in the set $S=\{x_1,x_2,\ldots\}$ must be eventually constant, so has limit in $S$, hence $S$ is closed. Define the function $f:S\to \mathbb R$ by $f(x_n)=n$, which is continuous because $S$ is a discrete set. By the **Tietze extension theorem**, we can extend $f$ to a continuous unbounded function $g:X\to\mathbb R$.

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by S being discrete, and why does it follow that $f$ is continuous?

Comment: I don't see why $f$ is well-defined, since nothing seems to prohibit having indices $m$ and $n$ with $m \neq n$ but $x_m = x_n$; in such a case, what is the value of $f$ at $x_n$ &mdash; is it $m$ or is it $n$.

Comment: @murray: OK but this has an easy fix right? A given point in the space can only appear finitely many times because $f(x_n) > n$ so we can just write a new sequence $y_1, y_2, ...$ where it's the same as the original but every time there's a previous element we just don't put it in the $y$-sequence. Now observe the $y$-sequence has no convergent subsequence also, so we can do everything else.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if the following [proof](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B3DmVmrIhlBhMTYxOGYyNTQtZWQxYS00NzgwLWFlMDItNzU1ZDZmNTUzZWY3/edit?hl=en_US&authkey=CMfYsckL&pli=1) works, but it uses the Tietze extension theorem, among other things, to prove the density of $C_{0}(\mathbb{R})$ in $L^{1}$.